# Break Pages With Table Rows CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic list and I wish there was a break when the size of the print paper exceeds, but many errors occur.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more detail. How are you generating this list?

Comment: use `@media print {
  footer {page-break-after: always;}
}`